# Paho(MQTT) client can't connect

Tags: python, ubuntu, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I'm using this python script to implement a basic Paho(MQTT) subscriber but under certain circumstances it doesn't invoke **on_connect**.

I tried the following, all with exactly the same code:

- Running in a Raspbery pi, broker on desktop Pc (Ubuntu). **Works**.
- Running in a Pc(Ubuntu), broker on the same Pc. **Doesn't work**.
- Running in a Pc(Ubuntu), broker on other Pc(Ubuntu). **Doesn't work**.
- Running in a Pc(Ubuntu), broker.hivemq.com as broker. **Works**.
- Running in a Pc(Ubuntu), broker.hivemq.com (it's IP) as broker. **Works**.

I also usually do:

- mosquitto_sub/pub in terminal in all previous combinations. **Works**.
- Official C++ paho wrapper in all previous combinations. **Works**.

Also tried all setup methods listed in the official website. So python's paho library doesn't seem to be getting along with my local broker unless I run it from my raspberry. But using the same broker works well with c++'s paho library and if using MQTT from the terminal. Any ideas of what can be happening?

```
     import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

     def on_connect(mqtt_client, obj, flags, rc):
         mqtt_client.subscribe("test")
         print "on_connect"

     def on_message(mqtt_client, obj, msg):
         print "on_message"

     mqtt_client = mqtt.Client()
     mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
     mqtt_client.on_message = on_message
     mqtt_client.connect("127.0.0.1",1883)
     mqtt_client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: Just checking, when you say exactly the same code, you are changing the ip address in the `mqtt_client.connect` function call as needed

Comment: Yes I'm changing it when neccesary. It shouldn't be that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem and changing the version of MQTT protocol in [Client's constructor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1#constructor-reinitialise) solved it.

```
mqtt_client = mqtt.Client("", True, None, mqtt.MQTTv31)
```

Since you do not specify the protocol, it uses the default one: MQTTv311.